# |Boostrap 5| Border colors don't change

Tags: border, bootstrap-5

I set my Bootstrap rules to change the basic colors (primary, secondary etc...)

Changes are OK for everything (buttons, hovers etc, tables etc) except border colors... and I don't understand why.

Here's some parts of my code. My array in `app.css`:

```css
//config Bootstrap colors set
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

$primary : #009f93;
$secondary : #ff9914;
$success : #69dc9e;
$info : #90c290;
$light : #e4f0f5;
$dark : #0b2027;

$theme-colors: (
        "primary":    $primary,
        "secondary":  $secondary,
        "success":    $success,
        "info":       $info,
        "warning":    $secondary,
        "danger":     $danger,
        "light":      $light,
        "dark":       $dark
);
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

and an example of the border use. I've also tried with a full border and it doesn't work also. And any of the color I've changed are rendered.

```html
<li class="nav-item border-bottom border-3 border-primary mb-2">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">
        <span data-feather="bar-chart-2">Rapports</span>         
    </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to @import all of bootstrap before the changes. Instead, @import the required SASS source files and then set the changes.

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap/functions";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap/variables";

/* Variable overrides */
$primary : #009f93;
$secondary : #ff9914;
$success : #69dc9e;
$info : #90c290;
$light : #e4f0f5;
$dark : #0b2027;

$theme-colors: (
        "primary":    $primary,
        "secondary":  $secondary,
        "success":    $success,
        "info":       $info,
        "warning":    $secondary,
        "danger":     $danger,
        "light":      $light,
        "dark":       $dark
);

@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap/";
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/88cNHdRdIK)

Comment: Perfect !! I've import the _functions.scss and _variables.scss and it's OK. The doc says it's not necessary but.... 

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/_functions.scss";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss";
```